# Inequality between taxicab metric and Euclidean metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Prove that in $\mathbb R^n$, $d_1 (x,y)\le{\sqrt n}d_2 (x,y)$. Here $d_1(x,y)=\sum|x_i-y_i|$ and $d_2(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum (x_i-y_i)^2}$.

I tried to square both sides and expand but do not think that I can prove that $n\lvert x_i -y_i\rvert<\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i -y_i\rvert$ for any i. Maybe this has something to do with Cauchy-Schwarz but I don't see how to use it.

Comment: Please don't assume that every little notation your book uses is universally recognized by everyone. What exactly do you mean by $d_1, d_2$?

Comment: $d_2$ is the euclidean metric

Comment: Okay, the more obvious one is down. Now what about the other one?

Comment: $d_1= \sum_{j=1}^n \lvert x_j - y_j\rvert$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $d_1 \leq \sqrt{n}\cdot d_2$ by CS inequality precisely.

Comment: wow I suddenly see. So basically we let $b_n$ in CS inequality be 1, is that right?

Comment: Yes, you got it. Good job !

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f,g$ defined on the set $\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n : x_i\geq 0 \quad\forall i\}$ by
$$
f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \text{ and } g(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2
$$
and we maximize $f$ under the constraint that $g = 1$. Lagrange multipliers will tell you that this is maximum when
$$
x_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \quad\forall 1\leq i\leq n \Rightarrow f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n) = \sqrt{n}
$$
Hence, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, consider
$$
y = \frac{x}{d_2(x,y)}
$$
Then $d_2(y,0) = 1$, whence $d_1(y,0) \leq \sqrt{n}$ and so
$$
d_1(x,0) \leq \sqrt{n}d_2(x,0)
$$
Now use the fact that $d_j(x,y) = d_j(x-y,0)$ for both $j=1, 2$.